Why is this quadric error matrix correct?
I am used tot he following formulation of a quadric error matrix.
Given a plane normal $n$ and a distance $d$ from the origin along the normal, we can define an implicit equation for the plane as $p \cdot n - d = 0$.
This in turns tells us that the formula $[n, -d] [p, 1]$ yields the signed distance from point $p$ to the plane. Thus $ [p, 1]^T ([n, -d]^T [n, -d]) [p, 1]$ is the squared distance from $p$ to the plane, by construction. Meaning that the 4x4 matrix $Q = ([n, -d]^T [n, -d])$ is the quadric error metric matrix.
Then if we have multiple planes we can define an error matrix as $E = \sum^n_{i=1} Q_i$, where each $Q_i$ is a plane error matrix like above.
Then the minimizer of $p^T E p$ is just given by $Ex = [0,0,0,1]$.
Once you solve that system you normalize based on the last coordinate and get an answer.
However, I recently saw this definition:

Where each $Q^{i,j}$ is the corresponding scalar entry of the original quadric matrix $E$ (or $Q$ in the paper).
I don't entirely understand why this formulation is correct. Why does this yield the correct minimizer? Why can you replace the bottom row with zeros and ones and get the correct result?
